# The expected read speed of SQL*PLUS

Tags: oracle, performance, sqlplus

The issue is many-fold but it boils down to this simple scenario: I have a Oracle Database Version 19.4.0.0.0 and SQL*PLUS Version 21.3.0.0.0 running on the **same** Red Hat Linux (I actually tried both local and remote connections, here let's just consider the local case to separate concerns...). I run this SQL statement:

```
SELECT "Date", "ID", "Name", "Value"
FROM "A_Table"
WHERE ("A_Table"."Date" >= '11-SEP-20' AND "A_Table"."Date" <= '11-SEP-21');
```

So basically I just want to fetch all the rows based on `Date` and the resultant file should be around 2GB in size. The statement works, but after using a wide range of techniques (ICYW, techniques including checking filesystem IO, network IO and file size regularly), I am sure that this `SELECT` statement can only fetch data at a speed of 2 MByte/s maximum (

**Edit1:** after revising my script following `@ik_zelf`'s answer, I get 8-9 MBytes/s with a local connection (same machine) and 4 Mbytes/s with a remote connection (within a LAN);

**Edit2:** after adding a `-FAST` option, following `@Andrew Sayer`'s comment, I get 50-60 MBytes/s with a local connection (same machine) and 10-15 Mbytes/s with a remote connection (within a LAN);
).

**Edit3:**
Get some results from `set autotrace traceonly statistics`:

```
122096809 rows selected.


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
         11  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
    2097347  consistent gets
    1994129  physical reads
        220  redo size
 4626657759  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
     269324  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
      24421  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          1  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
  122096809  rows processed
```

**Edit4:**
In my case, index is actually NOT used. However, this turns out to be not the cause of the issue. (But this means that some of the below observation is INcorrect)

Some extra observation and tuning:

1. An index is correctly built and this speed limit is NOT from Oracle finding the right data to send, but rather, all data are there ready to be sent, just somehow they cannot be sent at a speed higher than 8-9 MBytes/s--I observe that, at first few seconds, Oracle service will read hard drive at 300-500MB/s, after a short while (i.e., a few seconds), it stops reading and then the SELECT command starts showing results. So I believe that Oracle is done reading and organizing;
2. I set `arraysize` to 5,000, which, according to Oracle's manual, seems to be highest possible value (but sure I tried other values such as 100 as well)--this is particularly odd, I tried tuning this parameter when using `cx_Oracle`, it is very effective.
3. I also tried setting `SDU` to 65535.

Nothing seems working.

Is this the normal speed that I can expect from SQL*PLUS? (But I believe the answer is no, seems I tried using Python's `cx_Oracle` package which in turn, utilizing Oracle Instant Client to do the fetching, I can reach a speed of around 40MBytes/s, but that one has other issues which prevent us from using it at the moment...)

Thanks!

Comment: If you want sql*plus to extract lots of data fast, use fast mode (that’s not sarcasm, there’s a literal switch for it). You saying that you see the Oracle process running at 300+ Mb/s does not correspond to lookups via index - are you sure you’re not full scanning (and therefore reading way more data than you are having to transmit)? Your date filter is for a years worth of data, for reasonably sized tables if you want this to be fast, partitioning is a good idea. That said, why are you just spooling it to a file, what’s the actual purpose of that file? Expdp might be a more suitable solution

Comment: Additionally, always use the correct data type, you are comparing your column to a string. If your column is a date data type (it should be) then Oracle will have to implicitly convert your string to a date, you should do this explicitly, providing the date format (and using 4 digits for years)

Comment: Hi @AndrewSayer, firstly--yes! the -FAST option is much faster lol. Regarding the 300+ Mbytes/s read, I am not sure if index is play a big role. But my emphasis is in the later half--Oracle reaches 300+MB/s immediately after I execute my query, it also uses a lot of CPU and memory--my original idea is that, it implies Oracle is very busy. After a few seconds, hard drive IO, CPU goes to nearly zero, implying Oracle is done. This is the source of my feeling that Oracle gets the data ready within a few seconds since it is not working anymore, not necessarily because of indexing.

Comment: regarding the file issue, it is actually more complicated then the question...We need to convert this resultant table into a Python object, so that our program can further handle it. I tried using Python packages (i.e., `pyodbc` and `cx_Oracle`)to do this directly--there appears to be a memory leakage issue, basically the data is around 2GB in size, but my Python script uses more than 30GB (my workstation only has 30, so not sure how high they will be) to fetch them. So I am investigating the approach of saving everything to a csv, just for interoperability.

Comment: @AndrewSayer: I may explore using expdp or whatever format if Python can read them, I am also just aware that csv format enlarges the data quite a bit, so it may not be the ultimate solution, just investigating...

Comment: It’s a bit of an anti pattern to load up everything from your database into your application in one go. The data in the database is for many other users, your application should only need to see a few rows at a time. (Obviously there are always exceptions, but if you’re in this situation because you’re coming at it from the wrong direction, now is the time to turn around). If it is necessary, start with an extended sql trace (event 10046) of the entire process and upload it as a text dump somewhere with a link and we can advise on what can be done.

Comment: Hi @AndrewSayer, for the structure issue, yes I kind of agree that the current design is not very good to say the least, however, the team already has the infrastructure built around it...so at this moment I have to live with it...Regarding an sql trace, I searched on the Internet, but I am not quite sure what I should do...This link has a lot of examples: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof, should I follow one of them?..

Comment: Yes, whichever of those ways you can do (probably best to use the `ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context forever, level 8';` to start and `ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context off';` to finish from your session running the process. You can also use the `tracefile_identifier` if you’re not sure how to identify which file is yours.

Comment: Hi @AndrewSayer, after searching a while and ask my firm's DBA, the result I currently has is added as `edit3` of the original question. Is this the one you were interested in?

Answer (score 1):

You are not measuring the read speed. If you dig a bit deeper you will discover that most time is spent formatting the output and writing it to stdout.

For the real read speed a table scan will be quicker than an indexed read.

If you look in the wait events of your session, the event sqlnet more data to client will be the winner, if there are a lot of rows to write. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B16240_01/doc/doc.102/e16282/oracle_database_help/oracle_database_wait_bottlenecks_net_more_to_client_pct.html

If your real goal is to test your max io performance, use slob. See https://kevinclosson.net/category/oracle-io-performance/

Slob is server only, taking away all protocol and client overhead.

Comment: I actually set these parameters: `arraysize 5000`, `set colsep ,`, `set headsep off`, `set pagesize 0`, `set trimspool on`. Do you mean that I should turn off the SQL*PLUS stdout altogether?

Comment: Ah yes you are very correct--after turning off the stdout (following this link: https://www.toolbox.com/tech/oracle/question/how-can-i-stop-output-from-showing-in-the-sqlplus-screen-092010/), I get an output speed at around 8MBytes/s. Is this the upper limit then? Since we have index, my original thought is that the only bottleneck is my hard drive's IO--but 8Mbytes/s is definitely still far from it.

Comment: If you want to see the max scan speed, drop the index. Compared to dd it should come closer. Also make multi block read count larger.

Comment: Hi @ik_zelf, when saying "300MB/s speed", my emphasis is this: Oracle reaches 300+MB/s immediately after I execute my query, it also uses a lot of CPU and memory--my original idea is that, it implies Oracle is very busy. After a few seconds, hard drive I/O and CPU drop to nearly zero, implying Oracle is done. So my argument here is that my script is slow NOT because Oracle is busy finding and organizing the data to sent, but rather, Oracle is ready and just waiting the request to fetch those data. So my feeling is that, Oracle service is fine, it is SQL*PLUS that is causing the issue.

Comment: Yes, sqlplus is busy digesting and formatting. You could use bequeth connection to strip the tcp protocol overhead.

Comment: What you can do to better isolate is to run sqlplus on a laptop with a cpu with a high single core speed and a high speed network.

Comment: no when I say "300MB+", I mean the Oracle database service ,not my sqlplus client.

Comment: currently I am running both Oracle db instance and sql*plus on a server. I think CPU and network should not be a concern here. (But sure the original design is that Oracle DB instance and client (i.e. sql*plus in this case) are running on two different machines, but to make the case simple, when asking this question, I already moved everything to one single Red Hat server)

Comment: As @ik_zelf was saying, depending on how you connect sqlplus to the database, network latency (even the loopback connection introduces overhead) can still be an issue even when running on the same host as the database. You must use a bequeath connection - not TNS - to avoid all networking impact. It is not clear from your answer that this is what you are doing. Just running on the same host, _using the same TNS connection parameters as a remote client_, isn't enough.