# Possible memory leak of cx_Oracle/pyodbc/Oracle Instant Client?

Tags: oracle, memory, python, odbc

Let me first list all the relevant information...

- Oracle database Version 19.4.0.0.0
- Oracle instantclient version: 21.3.0.0.0
- OS version: RHEL 7.9 x64
- cx_Oracle version: 8.2
- pyodbc version: 4.0.32
- unixODBC driver version: 2.3.8
- Python version: 3.9.5

I tried both `pyodbc` and `cx_Oracle`, the issues are essentially the same. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
# cx_Oracle version of connection init
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host=[host], port=[port], sid=[sid])
con = cx_Oracle.connect(user=[username], password=[password], dsn=dsn)
# pyodbc version of connection init
con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=[driver-definition];DBQ=[host]:[port]/[service-name];UID=[username];PWD=[password]')

with con.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.arraysize = 100_000 # Only effective when using cx_Oracle
    sql = """
            SELECT "Date", "ID", "KeyName", "ValueName"
            FROM "A_Table"
            WHERE ("A_Table"."Date" >= '07-SEP-20' AND 
                   "A_Table"."Date" <= '07-SEP-21')
    """
    # So I just to get everything from the last year
    cursor.execute(sql)
    while True:
        fetched_rows = cur.fetchmany(num_rows)
        if not fetched_rows:
            break
         rows.extend(fetched_rows)
```

The issue is, the code can run, just it uses a LOT of memory. My guesstimate of the final resultant `rows` object should be no more than 2GB in size but the script uses up all my 30GB  memory and gets terminated by OS (i.e., I dont know exactly how much memory the script would like to allocate since it is not given the chance). Before the script gets killed, it asks for about 200 Mbytes of memory each second so my 30GB memory does not last for too long...At the moment it is killed, usually it fetches no more than 50% of the rows needed.

Here comes the really strange thing--I can avoid the above issue by commenting out `rows.append(row)`. That is, if I don't save the fetched rows and just keeps reading and discarding, the script becomes totally fine...

One may say: would it be possible that there is a mismatch between rows' actual size and `cx_Oracle`/`pyodbc`'s idea of their size? This is unlikely, I tried printing `cursor.description` and the result is the following:
`[('Date', <class 'cx_Oracle.DATETIME'>, 23, None, None, None, 0), ('ID', <class 'cx_Oracle.STRING'>, 9, 9, None, None, 0), ('KeyName', <class 'cx_Oracle.STRING'>, 53, 53, None, None, 0), ('ValueName', <class 'cx_Oracle.NUMBER'>, 127, None, 126, -127, 0)]`. Looks normal.

What if I do this instead:

```
    while True:
        fetched_rows = cursor.fetchmany():
        if not fetched_rows :
            break
        dcfr = copy.deepcopy(fetch_rows) 
        fetch_rows = None # we keep a deepcopy of fetched_rows, hoping it can release the object reference and space.
        rows.append(dcfr)
        gc.collect() # Manual garbage collection to avoid any delay
```

No, it won't solve the issue.
I tried using SQL*PLUS:

[The expected read speed of SQL*PLUS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299426/the-expected-read-speed-of-sqlplus)

It does NOT suffer from the same issue and it can reach a local read speed at 50MBytes/s. Any idea?...

Comment: I have processes running for months without any memory problems using the same tools. There still can be memory leaks but in simple code it’s a bit in likely. I wonder very much which business problem you are trying to solve. Just copying a database to memory does not make sense since the database handles this much better in most cases.

Comment: Hey @ik_zelf, yes this is exactly why it is so odd (and both `cx_Oracle` and `pyodbc` are failing the same way!)--the code is so simple--basically I just copy it from official document, but still it does not work as expected. I am trying to find out why. Regarding the business aspect--well I kind of agree with you--but this is not what I can change lol...so I have to live with it and try improving within my mandate as a team member...

Comment: Which python version?

Comment: just revised my question, it is 3.9.5. I also created an issue on `cx_Oracle`'s github: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/583

Comment: What is the size of dcfr?

Comment: `dcfr`? I think `dcfr` is just a copy of `fetch_rows` and `fetch_rows` is just a list of Python tuples. So it should be pretty small. But since you asked, I use `sys.getsizeof(dcfr)` to check its size. If `arraysize` is set to 100_000, `sys.getsizeof(dcfr)` returns 800,984 (bytes).